# Is it possible to see the chain code that is generated by Fabric Composer?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

How are users of Fabric Composer able to see and understand the chain code generated for transactions on their business network?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 6):

Fabric Composer does not directly generate chaincode. It uses a generic chaincode that maps models to chaincode tables and runs transaction processor functions in the javascript interpreter for GO,  [Otto](https://github.com/robertkrimen/otto).

The generic chaincode is [here](https://github.com/fabric-composer/fabric-composer/tree/master/packages/composer-runtime-hlfv1)